# what's the technical explanation for failure of vue binding mechanisim in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to vuejs and I stuck in this part of my code.
What's the technical explanation for failure of Vue binding mechanism in this scenarios.

The expected result should prevent check-boxes form being unchecked but the result is different!
Model data is fine but UI state is invalid.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    todos: function(){
        return [
          { text: "Item1", done: true },
          { text: "Item2", done: true },
          { text: "Item3", done: true },
          { text: "Item4", done: true }
        ]
      }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos()">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-model="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add :disabled="todo.done" to the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js only makes the `data` field reactive. Other methods are not `watched`.

You need to move `todos` under `data` for this to work.

```
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data() {
   return {
    todos: [
     { text: "Item1", done: true },
     { text: "Item2", done: true },
     { text: "Item3", done: true },
     { text: "Item4", done: true }
   ]
  }
 },
 methods: {
  toggle: function(todo){
    todo.done = !todo.done
  }
 }
})
```

Note that `data` can be a simple field or a method. The recommended way is to make it a method.

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-einstein-hvy6z) with your data.